# Saving memory and compile time

Tags: perl, runtime, compiler-optimization

Is there any way to save memory and compile time in perl using modules? For example not load all of the unneccessary, unused subs?

Or it is a good way if I split my subs to many different `pm` files, and then I load only neccessary modules? For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

sub mysub1() {
    use MySubsGroup1;
}
sub mysub2() {
    use MySubsGroup2;
}
```

This solution use less memory and get less compile time? Or what is the best practice to load only neccessary functions?

Comment: `use` runs at compile time, so putting it to subroutines makes no difference.

Comment: so there is no way to load only neccessary subs?

Answer (score 4):

From [`perldoc autouse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autouse.html)

> autouse - postpone load of modules until a function is used
>
> If the module Module is already loaded, then the declaration
>
> `use autouse 'Module' => qw(func1 func2($;$));`
>
> is equivalent to
>
> `use Module qw(func1 func2);`

Comment: There is also the Class::Autouse module on CPAN which can be used if autouse isn't compatible with the module you want to load delayed.

Answer (score 3):

`use` always runs in compile time. But `require` doesn't. So you can use `require Module;` just before any function call.

Of course, the module will be loaded only the first time `require` is executed (and stay loaded).

Mind that `use` also calls `import` on the loaded module and you may want to do that too. `use Module qw(f1 f2)` is a compile-time version of `require Module; Module->import(qw(f1 f3))`.