# Perl library usage

Tags: perl

Is there any benefit (w.r.t performance/memory usage) in including `use mylibrary` conditionally (assuming `mylibrary` is used only if condition is true) compared to adding `use mylibrary` on top of the script unconditionally?

```
# Script 1 (Unconditional use)
use mylibrary;
if($condition)
{
    # Do something with mylibrary
}

# Script 2 (Conditional use)
if($condition)
{
    use mylibrary;
    # Do something with mylibrary
}
```

Comment: You may be interested in `autouse` or `Class::Autouse`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026270/saving-memory-and-compile-time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`use` is a compile-time construct.  In your two cases, `mylibrary` is actually being imported in both of your "Unconditional" and "Conditional" cases.  If you want to import a library conditionally, use `require`, a run-time construct, instead.

```
if ($condition) {
    require mylibrary;
    # mylibrary->import;
    # ...
}
```

In such a case you lose some of the compile-time benefits of `use`.  For example, `require` does not call `mylibrary->import` at compile time, as `use` does.  You can call `import` yourself if you want, as I show above, but anything `import` does that has an effect at compile time will not have that effect when called at run time.

Suppose your module `mylibrary` exports a function `foo`.  Then this works:

```
use strict;
use mylibrary;  # exports function foo()
foo;
```

But this is an error:

```
use strict;
require mylibrary;
mylibrary->import; # too late to notify Perl's parser about the foo() function
foo; # error; unknown function
```

As to whether there's any benefit to doing so, there can be if `mylibrary` is expensive to import.  Most of the time, probably not.

Comment: My major use case for require and import is loading separate stuff when.threading.

Comment: Are you sure about your last snippet causing an error? `perl -Mstrict -wE 'require Cwd; Cwd->import; say getcwd()'` Also, I prefer the [`if` module](http://perldoc.perl.org/if.html) for conditional loading.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I was thinking of calling subroutines without parentheses.  I've updated my example.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve conditional loading, including the side benefits of the `use` (the calling of ->import, and execution at compilation time) with the `if` pragma: http://perldoc.perl.org/if.html

```
use if $Config{usethreads}, 'Library::Requiring::Threads';
```

One caveat, of course, is that the `if` expression is executed at compile time, so everything it depends on must also be known and available at compile time.